# Combining graduated styling with dots/stripes using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style

I am using QGIS and I am making a heat map, but want to mark the ones that have missing data with spots.

Is it possible to add dots/stripes to my graduated colour styling?

As far as I can see it is only possible to use simple fill.

Comment: And if possible, point us to an image or draw a picture of what you'd like your style to look like. That would be great.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.